# reading messages as conversation items

Tags: android, sms, message

i am developing a sms messaging app as my first attempt at android development, i am able to get the list of conversations using Telephony.Sms.Conversations. but i am not able to find any api that lets me fetch all messages that belong to a particular conversation (like a thread of messages). is there any way to get those messages or the only way is to get all messages to and from that specific person manually fron sent and inbox and then sort them according to time? any help will be appreciated. i have been looking all over the web for a week now and havent been able to find anything.

Comment: so `android.provider.Telephony.Threads` is not what you are looking for?

Comment: @pskink i get the thread id for a recipient from that. but how do i get messages related to that thread id

Comment: it has a `CONTENT_URI`, i didn't use it before but maybe you can just append thread id to form a complete `Uri`

Comment: thanks dude. i am a .net developer. the lack of detailed documentation like msdn is just depressing.